# Find all elements with same class but exclude the clicked element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

At the event of a click I need to fire some actions. Problem is that I need to exclude the clicked element. Let's say that I click at the first .child then actions just be applied ONLY to the second and third .child elements.

```
  $('.child').on("click", function() {
    $(".parent").find(".child").DO_SOMETHING();
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) like this

```
  $('.child').on("click", function() {
    $(".parent").find(".child").not($(this));
  });
```

**Example**

```js
$('.child').on("click", function() {
    $(".parent").find(".child").css("color", "black").not($(this)).css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">One</div>
    <div class="child">Two</div>
    <div class="child">Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to create an entire jQuery object, just `not(this)` will work.